# Writing Arrays to Binary Files Takes a Long Time in Python

Tags: python

I have a Zynq board (RFSoC) with an embedded Linux installed on it. I have written a Python program that controls my FPGA. In this Python program, I want to write the received data from the FPGA into binary files on the SD card of the board. However, I have encountered a strange issue. The for loop responsible for writing the newly received data into the binary file sometimes takes much more time than usual. It seems that the program stops working for a couple of seconds.

Can anyone help me solve this issue? It could introduce a serious bottleneck in my system.

Here is my code snippet:

```
        for i in range(int(self.pulseNumber)):

            self.dma0_recv.transfer(output_buffer0)
            self.dma1_recv.transfer(output_buffer1)
            self.dma2_recv.transfer(output_buffer2)
            self.dma3_recv.transfer(output_buffer3)
            self.dma0_recv.wait()
            self.dma1_recv.wait()
            self.dma2_recv.wait()
            self.dma3_recv.wait()

            self.data_source_mmio.write(0, 12)

            begin_writing = time.time()

            filename = self.experiment_name + "_waveform" + str(i).zfill(4) + "_channel0.bin"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            #np.save(file_path, output_buffer0)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(output_buffer0.tobytes())

            filename = self.experiment_name + "_waveform" + str(i).zfill(4) + "_channel1.bin"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            #np.save(file_path, output_buffer1)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(output_buffer1.tobytes())

            filename = self.experiment_name + "_waveform" + str(i).zfill(4) + "_channel2.bin"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            #np.save(file_path, output_buffer2)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(output_buffer2.tobytes())

            filename = self.experiment_name + "_waveform" + str(i).zfill(4) + "_channel3.bin"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            #np.save(file_path, output_buffer3)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(output_buffer3.tobytes())

            end_writing = time.time()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GyuJ.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you expect it should take a certain amount of time (consistently)? Can you reproduce the problem in any other way *without* the board being involved (e.g., using the same SD card directly plugged in to the computer)? Have you tried to look up documentation for the board? Did you try using actual profiling tools instead of trying to check the wall-clock time manually at different points in the program?

Comment: What's you bandwidth requirement? For how much is the SD card rated? Have you checked the SD card performance with a disk benchmark or even something simple like `dd if=/dev/zero of=file_on_disk bs=65536 count=xxx`? It very much looks like the OS just blocks while trying to flush changes to disk but the disk is too slow

Comment: Also, is your main concern that you don't have enough write performance (in average MiB/s) or that the delay causes jitter / other visible side effects? Because the second issue can be solved with offloading the actual write command to a background thread connected via a queue. The first one probably needs better hardware

Comment: Thank you @Homer512 for you message.
1- My main concern is not the write performance (average MiB/s). What I want is that my system should work consistantly, even with a low write speed.
2- I have a pretty much good SDCard (Delkin Devices with 256 MB/s rate write speed). It was the fastest that I could find on the market.
3- When I run the benchmark command that you said (time dd if=/dev/zero of=file_on_disk bs=65536 count=4096), I get the following result:
268435456 bytes (268 MB, 256 MiB) copied, 0.931392 s, 288 MB/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash drives having latency spikes isn't entirely unheard of. You might want to investigate that further, but if you just want to be done with it, I suggest decoupling the writing from the rest of your application.

In general, Linux rate-limits applications that write to disk by blocking the write calls. Asynchronous, nonblocking IO doesn't work. So the only way to avoid blocking the main thread is to use background threads. You can simply use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html) for this. However, I recommend doing a few extra steps:

1. Limit the number of operations that can be in-flight. If your disk really is too slow, you don't want to buffer until you run out of memory and crash your process. Better set a conservative limit that is big enough to compensate for the latency spikes but stays within the limits of your system
2. Use a simple scheme to report write errors by getting raised exceptions back into the main thread

There are plenty of ways of doing this, here is one example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import collections
from concurrent import futures


class WriteQueue:
    """Asynchronous file writing

    Attributes:
    maxmem -- memory in bytes. If not None or zero, attempts to write will
        block if more than this amount of file content is queued up.
        Avoids crashing the application with OOM conditions
    usedmem -- amount of bytes currently in queue
    executor -- ThreadPoolExecutor for doing the actual work
    finished -- deque of (future, memory) tuples with the queued up operations
    """
    def __init__(self, maxmem=None):
        """Initializes the attributes"""
        self.maxmem = maxmem
        self.usedmem = 0
        self.executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
        self.finished = collections.deque()

    def close(self):
        """Waits for all operations to finish"""
        try:
            while self.finished:
                future, mem = self.finished.popleft()
                self.usedmem -= mem
                future.result()
        finally:
            self.executor.shutdown()

    def __enter__(self):
        """Implements context manager interface"""
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Implements context manager interface. Waits for queued operations"""
        self.close()

    def _wait_for_space(self, required):
        """Blocks until the queue has enough memory"""
        if not self.maxmem:
            return
        while self.usedmem and self.maxmem - self.usedmem < required:
            future, mem = self.finished.popleft()
            self.usedmem -= mem
            # careful: this may raise an exception. We want the object state
            # to be consistent if that happens
            future.result()

    def __call__(self, path, content):
        """Creates a binary file at path and writes the content to it"""
        mem = len(content)
        self._wait_for_space(mem)
        def write():
            with open(path, 'wb') as outfile:
                outfile.write(content)
        future = self.executor.submit(write)
        self.finished.append((future, mem))
        self.usedmem += mem
        # flush finished operations
        while self.finished:
            future, mem = self.finished[0]
            if not future.done():
                return
            self.finished.popleft()
            self.usedmem -= mem
            future.result() # may raise exception


maxmem = 128 * 1024**2 # 128 MiB
with WriteQueue(maxmem) as write:
    for i in range(1000):
        write(f"/tmp/foo_{i}.bin", b'0' * 1024)
```